# AndEngine GLES1 Texture Bleeding, and Padding

Tags: android, andengine

Ive been trying to figure this out for hours.

Is there ANY way to add padding to a SVG's to avoid Texture Bleeding in GLES1? I know it is built with a method in GLES2 to avoid texture bleeding, but what are ways to do it in GLES1?

I have ALOT of texture bleeding with my SVG's and some bleeding with my Sprites.